# AppSync subtract/add day to current day in request mapping template

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl

In my **AppSync** mapping request template, I need to add or subtract day from the current date.

All I could find are just formatting and parsing time helpers: [Time Helpers in $util.time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html.)

```
#set( $todayString = $util.time.nowISO8601())
```

todayString is then like: 2019-08-23T09:00:00.000Z but I need to set new variables representing same time but one day prior current date or one day after it with the same formatting.

Is it possible at all using only vtl - mapping request template for my DynamoDB datasource?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by using epoch time utils. Since it returns long, we can manipulate dates like in this sample and then convert it back to ISO8601 using existing time helper which accepts long value and returns formatted one further needed.

```
#set( $currentTimeEpoch = $util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds())
#set( $fromStartEpoch = $currentTimeEpoch + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
#set( $currentTime = $util.time.epochMilliSecondsToISO8601($currentTimeEpoch))
#set( $fromStart = $util.time.epochMilliSecondsToISO8601($fromStartEpoch))
```